# Redirect a user when box is closed

Tags: html, popup

I have a javascript popup context menu with a button below it with close. That button when pressed close will continue to the next page. If a user dont click the close button and decides to click outside the popup box it will not redirect the user. What function for javascript can i add if a user click outside the box it will redirect them without clicking the close button inside the box. using a osx-modal-content plugin

How its triggered*

```
<input type='button' name='osx' value='Click Here To Enter The Website!' class='osx demo'/></a>
```

plugin page (link)

OSX STYLE DIALOG ** OSX STYLE DIALOG ** OSX STYLE DIALOG **

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

This is something that i have for the close function**

```
close: function (d) {
    var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
    d.container.animate(
        {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
        500,
        function () {
            self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
        }
```

Comment: What popup plugin are you using. Check the api. If found, add a hook and do window.location

Comment: Im using a osx-modal-content

Comment: Link to plugin page? How are you triggering the action?

Comment: I will update the post to how im triggering it and put the link to the plugin

Comment: Its called OSX STYLE DIALOG on http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do stuff on close:

```
$("#element-id").modal({
      onClose: function () {
          window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
     }
});
```

If you had an element added like:

```
// Load dialog on click
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

    return false;
});
```

Change that to

```
// Load dialog on click
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
          onClose: function () {
              window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
         }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: should i add that in my js or script in html

Comment: where you want. just as long as you remember where it is.

Comment: oh so since its included with a element id it can be placed anywhere and it will automatically be found. ok thanks just making sure

Comment: Ive added that, now the way that its triggered it dosent work anymore

Comment: I added an example. If you are already triggering that, just add the content from the curly braces and replace stackoverflow with whatever you want.

Comment: Look at the close function i just added above